# How can I compile the Android SDK with low RAM?

Tags: java, android-source

I'm trying to compile the Android SDK (version 11) via [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) scripts at *gitlab.com/android-rebuilds/auto*.
For various reasons, I have to use equipment that has 8 GB of RAM. The storage space is huge.

The scripts have been modified to work ([SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) issue), and I've also added a huge amount of swap memory (currently 315 GB).
I also added [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) memory.

I added values in the *build.sh* and *build-sys-img.sh* scripts,
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, JAVA_OPTIONS and _JAVA_OPTION = "-Xmx270g" to allocate a large portion of the swap to the compiler.

I also used `make -j1` instead of `make $(nproc)`.

Despite all the steps, I still get errors, like Java Heap Space.
The errors varied occasionally, but the general pattern was as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:4030)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.newString(StringLatin1.java:715)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1879)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:1913)
    at com.intellij.lang.impl.PsiBuilderImpl$RelativeTokenTextView.get(PsiBuilderImpl.java:1161)
    at com.intellij.lang.java.parser.JavaParserUtil$TrailingWhitespacesAndCommentsBinder.getEdgePosition(JavaParserUtil.java:88)
    at com.intellij.lang.impl.PsiBuilderImpl.balanceWhiteSpaces(PsiBuilderImpl.java:1116)
    at com.intellij.lang.impl.PsiBuilderImpl.prepareLightTree(PsiBuilderImpl.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.lang.impl.PsiBuilderImpl.buildTree(PsiBuilderImpl.java:910)
    at com.intellij.lang.impl.PsiBuilderImpl.getTreeBuilt(PsiBuilderImpl.java:905)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.JavaElementType$ICodeBlockElementType.parseContents(JavaElementType.java:156)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseableElement.lambda$ensureParsed$0(LazyParseableElement.java:206)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseableElement$$Lambda$213/0x00000001004e5440.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.performPsiModification(DebugUtil.java:553)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseableElement.ensureParsed(LazyParseableElement.java:205)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseableElement.getFirstChildNode(LazyParseableElement.java:254)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseablePsiElement.getFirstChild(LazyParseablePsiElement.java:90)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseablePsiElement.acceptChildren(LazyParseablePsiElement.java:104)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.visitElement(JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.java:43)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaElementVisitor.visitCodeBlock(JavaElementVisitor.java:52)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiCodeBlockImpl.accept(PsiCodeBlockImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositePsiElement.acceptChildren(CompositePsiElement.java:81)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.visitElement(JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.java:43)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaElementVisitor.visitStatement(JavaElementVisitor.java:259)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaElementVisitor.visitBlockStatement(JavaElementVisitor.java:32)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiBlockStatementImpl.accept(PsiBlockStatementImpl.java:67)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.LazyParseablePsiElement.acceptChildren(LazyParseablePsiElement.java:106)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.visitElement(JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.java:43)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaElementVisitor.visitCodeBlock(JavaElementVisitor.java:52)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiCodeBlockImpl.accept(PsiCodeBlockImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositePsiElement.acceptChildren(CompositePsiElement.java:81)
    at com.intellij.psi.JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.visitElement(JavaRecursiveElementVisitor.java:43)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
09:03:17 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Additionally, I am attaching a larger error package on this page: https://pastebin.com/YNN0fAp2

How can I fix this problem?